# How to Generate Random Password in Codeigniter for forgot password

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hello I am working with Codeigniter and I want to generate the random password.

I developed signup functionality using

```
crypt($password)
```

login functionality check password following.

```
if (crypt($password, $hashed_password) === $hashed_password)
{
    return $query->result();
}
```

**I am developing Forgot functionality.**

How to send random generated password to user mail When I am using crypt() login time.

Comment: don't send the password in email, instead in the email provide a link with token that points to a reset/create password page where the user will have to input a new password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below function to generate random password.

```
function random_password() 
{
    $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
    $password = array(); 
    $alpha_length = strlen($alphabet) - 1; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
    {
        $n = rand(0, $alpha_length);
        $password[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($password); 
}
echo random_password();
```

Comment: @Hassh   after generated password it can be check crypt() functionality.

Comment: You can use echo crypt(random_password()) after function.

Comment: Please try using above suggested way.

Comment: really helpful function thank you, i have tweaked it slightly to set the length as a variable

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without using array or for loop.
Using inbuilt function.

```
function random_password($length = 8) {
    $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+=-<>?/,.';
    $password = str_shuffle($alphabet);
    return substr($password, 0, $length);
}
echo random_password(10);
```